# What is the professional term for the combination of the selection in n out of the total m elements?

Tags: algorithm

I know the number of combinations is called nCr, but what about all the exact outcomes?

For example:
I have 3 elements `a,b,c` and for the param 2, I will have outcomes

`ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb`

I want to search different implementations of this. but I don't know what term should I input in google.

Comment: Maybe you mean "permutations" instead of "combinations"?

Comment: however is "permutations" only for the case of m=n?

Comment: Well "ab" and "ba" are permutations of "a" and "b", isn't that what you asked?

Comment: I suppose there will be a term `myverbize` like: `myverbize a,b,c of 2 is ab ac ba bc ca and cb`

Comment: So "number of k-combinations"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations

Comment: @RogerRowland The is a helpful information and I guess "Enumeration of k-combinations" would be a proper answer.

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi "Enumeration" is not really a mathematical term, maybe you want "set of combinations"

Comment: I would call {ab ac ba bc ca} (the collection of) all possible subsets of {a b c} with exactly two members.

Comment: though it is closed but if anyone is still interested in it. I have a better answer in the comment of my question in math stackexhange. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397076/what-is-the-professional-term-for-the-combination-of-the-selection-in-n-out-of-t?noredirect=1#comment849997_397076

Answer (score 4):

Just realized your question is basically wrong.

You are speaking about combinations yet you are expecting results like "ab" and "ba". A basic property of combinations is the fact they are unordered, that is, for a set {a, b, c}, 2-combinations will be {ab}, {ac}, {bc}, nothing else.

The term you are looking for is a **variation** or **partial permutation**. For variations, the order of elements matters.

Comment: can you give more information about variation and partial permutation?

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi Anything you want to know - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is a link for anything I want to know. at least it doesn't include what you have say, `variation`. If you are interested in it. I have a better answer in the comment of my question in math stackexhange. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397076/what-is-the-professional-term-for-the-combination-of-the-selection-in-n-out-of-t?noredirect=1#comment849997_397076

Comment: `variation` is just another name for `partial permutation` or `k-permutation`.